# Removing newsletter subscription "checkbox" at onepage checkout page

Tags: onepage-checkout, checkbox

I have just migrated my store to a new domain.

But I have an error at the one-page checkout page with "2" newsletter subscription checkboxes...supposedly still referring to the old domain name.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Magento StackExchange! could you please specify what version of magento are you using?

Comment: you can do it in a dirty way :) using `CSS` , just hide it , or remove it with javascript :) . But it is not recommended !

Comment: I am not a magento developer but am code savvy enough to follow detailed steps if properly guided